# Better markdown support for SO links

Tags: feature-request, markdown, hyperlinks

## Short version

Make this:

```
Some text [1] blah blah

...

[1]:https://stackoverflow.com/q/17134929/1544337
```

Into this:

> [Overlay a background-image with an rgba background-color](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17134929/1544337)

**Note**: I'm only talking about the links to Stack Overflow itself. Not about other websites!

## Long version

I like to put all the references I use in a post at its bottom. There's syntax for that:

```
[the-text][1]

...

[1]:http://the-url...
```

I also like the feature that SO-links are replaced by their title, like this:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/q/17134929/1544337
```

> [Overlay a background-image with an rgba background-color](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17134929/1544337) (instead of the bare link)

As far as I know, this last thing only works when you put the bare link in the body of the question, so you lose the advantage of the reference on the end of the post. Is this correct?

I tried this:

```
Some text [1] blah blah

...

[1]:https://stackoverflow.com/q/17134929/1544337
```

However, that results in:

> Some text [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17134929/1544337) blah blah

Wouldn't it be better if we changed that to show the title instead?

**Note**: I'm only talking about the links to Stack Overflow itself. Not about other websites!

---

There's a workaround:

```
[https://stackoverflow.com/q/17134929/1544337][1]

...

[1]:https://stackoverflow.com/q/17134929/1544337
```

But that would mean that when you change the link at the bottom, you have to change the link above as well. Not useful.

---

It is possible to make a link text with `[link-text](link-url)`, but that would mean that

- the URL is in the body, which I didn't want, to have a good overview
- you have to copy the title of the question yourself

Comment: Isn't this already done?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII no, try it :)

Comment: Just write `Some text http://stackoverflow.com/q/17134929/1544337 blah blah blah` if you want to take advantage of the automatic title-to-text. Putting the links at the bottom isn’t *that* great. Your proposed syntax conflicts with Markdown and isn’t very easy to read, so…

Comment: @minitechη for long posts, with many references, it is - what isn't easy about this syntax? Could you explain that? And how does it conflict with MD? I'm not an expert :)

Comment: @CamilStaps: No, because you lose context. The link (when you write it nicely) provides important information — for example, the title when you copy the “best” link (`http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184633/better-markdown-support-for-so-links`). Putting it at the bottom makes the links lose context, makes them harder to see if you want to just use `[1]`, and have to be renumbered all the time in a large reference post. Or get out of order, which defeats the point, in my opinion.

Comment: @CamilStaps: It conflicts with MD (maybe not all implementations? This one anyways) in that you can do `See [the docs]` and then put `[the docs]: http://example.com/whatever` at the bottom (a style I like a lot better than numbers, when possible `:)`, as it provides that context)

Comment: @minitechη oh, hey! I didn't know _that_ was possible! (the `the docs` example) Thanks :) but yes, now I see it conflicts, could you write an answer for that?

Answer (score 4):

Edit: There are a lot of problems with this request, but here are the major ones:

- What do you do when a link dies?
- Many titles are bad and should be paraphrased or described differently altogether.
- Given the above, since people take the path of least resistance, they will likely use the bad title even if it's obviously bad.

---

There is already a better markdown syntax for links. I suggest not using the one you've listed.

Instead, try this:

```
 [link text](link)
```

Edit this post to see how I [create this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184633/better-markdown-support-for-so-links).

Comment: That would mean you have to copy the link title, and the link would be in the body, not at the bottom.

Comment: @CamilStaps Once you copy the title, you can also use `[question title][1]` and at the bottom `[1]:http://...`.

Comment: @Camil Typically you don't want to copy the entire title over; just a few words suffice. And what's bad about the link being in the body? Nobody sees unrendered text.

Comment: For long answers, it gets very messy and unclear.

Comment: @DanielFischer true, but that wouldn't update when the title changes, and also mean you have to copy the title (not a big deal, but this would make it easier :))

Comment: @Camil That's why the other syntax exists - if it's unclear with this method, you can move the links to the bottom.

Comment: Yes, and then you'd have to copy the title. This would make it easier, not? :)

Comment: @Camil Titles are long, and often not very descriptive. While this would work for _certain_ links, it's generally _much_ better to summarize the content, and then just add a link.

Comment: In some cases, in some others not. For those others, this would be useful. And is there a reason why you wouldn't want it? Nobody really uses the `[1]` syntax.

Comment: @Camil Yes; the reason I wouldn't want that syntax is because it would encourage people to post nondescriptive links.

Comment: I think the real problem there is that the titles aren't descriptive and should be edited. I also think we should agree on being in a disagreement here :) let's see what the community thinks.

Comment: @Camil The difference is, you can't edit a website's title.

Comment: Wow, I'm not talking about _all_ websites. Just the SO links! Sorry, I'll edit my question to clarify that!

Comment: For all websites I can understand you wouldn't find the titles descriptive enough, of course :)

Answer (score 2):

This conflicts with Markdown a little bit, as this:

```
[Hello] world!

…

[Hello]: http://example.com
```

Renders as:

> [Hello](http://example.com) world!
>
> …

Sure, it could be special-cased, but I don’t think, personally, that a question link right in line with the text is such a bad thing. It gives you the title instead of just a number.

Comment: Sorry for the really late follow-up on that. :(